# How to read an .lcf file which is in asset folder in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, file-read

I have loaded `.lcf` file in `Assets` folder and I set build action as `Content`. I get an exception which says that file cannot be found.

This is how I read `.lcf` file from assets folder and store it in a `byte` array:

```
byte[] buf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("custom.lcf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [AssetManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/) to read files from Assets

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
byte[] data;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;

using (Stream input = assets.Open ("custom.lcf")) {
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
      int read;
      while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
          ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
      data = ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used `Assets.Open()` directly rather than declaring a reference to `AssetManager` first, but the rest of it worked, thanks!